# C++ Form Opening Error

Tags: c++, forms

In my Visual C++ App, I have been trying to open the form called "MyApp.h", from a form called "FrmProps.h". I have already been able to open MyApp.h from one form, and "FrmProps.h" from "MyApp.h", but when I want to open "MyApp.h" from "FrmProps.h", I get an error, saying 'The identifier MyApp^ is invalid'.

The code I am using is (FrmProps.h):

```
#include "MyApp.h"
```

---

```
MyApp^ myapp = gcnew MyApp();
myapp->Show();
myapp->Text = textBox1->Text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be due to the form being declared twice: maybe have a look at header guards to avoid this.